# Getting error as planner returned Bad hint while npm Test?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Query is executing fine but when I am running test case it's giving me error processing query -planner returned bad hint.

```
db.encounters.find({"CId": "", "Type.Name": "" }, {"DTTM": 1, "Type": 1, "message":1, "irisThreads": 1, "AppointmentStatus": 1})
             .hint({ CId : 1, "Type.Name": 1})
             .sort({"message.lastUpdatedDate":1})
```

I have index on CId and Type.Name .and simple db unit test case I have wrote but failing :(

Comment: please add your test code, and maybe the content of your test database

Comment: I have Simple mockgoose test case - describe.only('Encounter Controller', () => {
    describe('/GET communication encounters', () => {
        it('Should get communication encounters in desc order', (done) => {
            request.get('/api/ehr/patients/120000101999900P123/encounters/communication?channel=SMS&sortDir=1').then(resp => {
                resp.should.have.status(200);
                assert.isArray(resp.body);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});